# How to convert Json string with array of objects to a datatable?

Tags: json, vb.net, datatable

Code converts the json string to table. But my problem is, it bypass the Array Chars. So only two fields are printed on the table. It kind of skips the middle field: "Chars"

```
Dim JsonStr As String = "[{""Name"": ""Banana Pudding"", ""Chars"": [""abc"",""xyz""],""ID"": ""143""}]"
        tb = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)(JsonStr)
        GridView1.DataSource = tb
        GridView1.DataBind()
```

Comment: It doesnt bypass it bit it stores the array *object* in column 1.  You'll have to work out a way to unpack the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your database does not support array as a string, actually I do not know any db that do the coerce for a string to array, you have to change the value of Chars to a simple type, break it and it will work.
You may test your code with a binary field instead of string in your table, you did not mention which DBMS are you using, so I can not be more specific. but using a binary field, worth a shot, try it before breaking array to simple types.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Salutations and greetings generally do not add anything to the question/answer, and are frowned upon by the SO community.

Comment: Sam, Thanks for the advice, and please accept my apology, I have deleted the comments, they were very rude and I just don't know why I was a jerk that day.

Comment: No worries.  We all have days that irritate us.  I appreciate the note, thank you.